# Https Jquery Client to access https rest web

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

I am trying to call a https rest webservice server using jquery. 
for example, suppose the REST URL is https://server.com/api/user/test.
Now if I access this link using browser, it returns me the required json data .

But if I use the below jquery client, it is not able to connect to the webservice.

```
       $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: "https://server.com/api/user/test",
      success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
           alert(data);
         },

         error: function (jqXHR, status) {
             alert(status);
         }
```

Can someone tell me how to access an https restful webservice using Jquery

Comment: Are you trying to access from the same server?

Comment: Open your browser's developer console and look for an error message. If the request is being blocked for some reason an error should pop up there.

Comment: Is you're Ajax call coming from a page whose domain matches `server.com`?  If not, it's probably a CORS related issue.  If you have control over `server.com`, you can set headers in the response to whitelist your domain or all domains, but without that, you will have a hard time making Ajax calls across domains.

Comment: ssilas... the REST api resides in the server and I am trying to access the service from  the local machine using jquery/ajax

Comment: Rogers...what is the difference between accessing the https rest  url directly from the browser and accessing the same url using ajax.Why this works fine when I use the first method